# What's the purpose of extending Java serializable class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does a class implements Serializable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298782/why-does-a-class-implements-serializable-interface)

I'm using a tutorial found here: http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/ee/entity

I'm wondering why this class extends `Serializable`?  I've read the description of this class and I don't understand the importance of `serialVersionUID` and why it's necessary for my model.

Comment: possible duplicates: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298782/why-does-a-class-implements-serializable-interface 2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970891/who-actually-implements-serializable-methods 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441196/why-java-needs-serializable-interface

Comment: As for the question regarding why **this particular** class needs to implement `Serializable`, see the most voted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020904/when-and-why-jpa-entities-should-implement-serializable-interface)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't extend a class - it implements the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) *interface*, which is basically just a marker interface to say "I'm fine to be serialized".

The idea is to be able to transparently serialize instances of the class - potentially for caching or other purposes, I'm not sure in this case. The `serialVersionUID` field is just part of the versioning that Java binary serialization uses.

Comment: @imAGin: Yes, it looks like that tutorial is no longer available. I've removed the link.